# ROS2 Adding a library from another package to a library

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can add a library to executable however my main problem I could not add a library to another library.

My question is as follows: How can I add a_library in package A to b_library in package B.

https://answers.ros.org/question/357633/how-to-create-a-ros2-library/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403777/ros2-adding-a-library-from-another-package-to-a-library/) by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2022-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2022-07-15**:
Could you post what you have tried so far and the error message that you are getting? It certainly will be easier to narrow it down that way.

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2022-07-15**:
Have you tried this out?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56560309/how-to-link-shared-library-in-ament-tool-ros

**Comment by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) on 2022-07-15**:
Roberto your post is also usefull but there are many question stackoverflow and answers.ros but I did not get which is the true. However these 2 lines are keyword to also docs.ros is very usefull.

https://docs.ros.org/en/crystal/Contributing/Migration-Guide.html

```
ament_export_libraries(LibB)
ament_export_include_directories(include)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem. I use vscode with debugging however there was a problem. I deleted install and build folders and rebuild it. It solved after rebuild.

Package A a_library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(package_A)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(b_library REQUIRED)

set(dependencies
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
)

include_directories(include)


add_library(a_library SHARED src/a_library.cpp ) 
ament_target_dependencies(a_library ${dependencies} b_library)

add_executable(a_node src/a_node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(a_node  ${dependencies} b_library)
target_link_libraries(a_node a_library)



install(TARGETS a_node a_library
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

Package B b_library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(package_B)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

set(dependencies
  rclcpp
  std_msgs
)

include_directories(include)

add_library(b_library SHARED src/b_library.cpp) 
ament_target_dependencies(b_library ${dependencies})
ament_export_libraries(b_library)
ament_export_include_directories(include)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

install(
  TARGETS b_library
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

---

Originally posted by [bekirbostanci](https://answers.ros.org/users/45026/bekirbostanci/) with karma: 76 on 2022-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2022-07-22**:
I am glad to hear that you have solved the problem.